# Doesn't show data in the select

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json.net, asp.net-ajax

It doesn't show me anything in my input.

This is my script function on my view:

```
<script>
var Caracteristicas = [];

function LoadCaracteristicas(element) {
    if(Caracteristicas.length === 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'@Url.Action("GetCaracteristicas","Inspeccion")',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                Caracteristicas = data;
                alert(data);
                renderCaracteristica(element)
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        renderCaracteristica(element);
    }
}

function renderCaracteristica(element) {
    var $ele = $(element);
    $ele.empty();
    $ele.append($('<option/>').val('0').text('Select'));
    $.each(Caracteristicas, function (i, val) {
        $ele.append($('<option/>').val(val.Id_Caracteristica).text(val.Descripcion));
    })
}
```

My Select where I want to show the data:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <td>Caracteristica</td>
        <td>Resultado</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mycontainer" id="mainrowCateristica">
        <td>
            <select id="IDCateristicas" class="form-control"> ----- Show Data
                <option>Select</option>
            </select>
            <span class="error">Seleccione una Caracteristica</span>
        </td>
        <td>

                <input type="radio" id="RadioOK" name="resultado" value="1"> OK<br>
                <input type="radio" id="RadioNOK" name="resultado" value="0"> NOK<br>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="BtnAdd" value="Agregar" style="width:80px" class="btn btn-success" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My Controller Function:

```
public JsonResult GetCaracteristicas()
    {
        CalidadEntities db = new CalidadEntities();
        var data = from c in db.Caracteristicas select c;
        return Json(data.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The controller suppose that it passs data in the function JsonResult, but in the select it doesn't show me anythibg.

In my view at the begining:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                LoadCaracteristicas($("#IDCateristicas"));
            };
```

Comment: And what does the `alert(data)` show you ?

Comment: Does the GetCaracteristicas() function return any value? from C#

Comment: I could not find where you are calling `LoadCaracteristicas()`. Do you have this call?

Comment: The alert(data) don't show anything, and yes a make a breakpoint and there is all the data in my var data in GetCaracteristica()

Comment: your code is working fine in my project.

Comment: I tested your code, `alert(data)` shows data!

Comment: Yes it show me data when a send a message, like a var = "Hello", if convert to list to it show me H,e,l,l,o. But when I send data from my model its doesn't show it. And in the select doesn't show me anything, I don't know if I a need a script o jquery or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it. I change my function of my controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetCaracteristicas()
    {
        int tipoc = 10; -- Temporaly
        CalidadEntities db = new CalidadEntities();
        var data = (from c in db.Caracteristicas where c.Id_TComponente == tipoc
                    select new {
                        Id_Caracteristica =c.Id_Caracteristica,
                        Descripcion = c.Descripcion
                    }).ToList();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I don't why but its the only way it work for me. Thanks for all.